# How do I programmatically add a view right under the navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm trying to add a view to a `UINavigationController` with its top aligned with the navigation bar's bottom.

I tried using constraints by adding the following to my `UINavigationController` subclass:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
           self.label = UILabel()
    self.label?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.label?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.label?.text = "label text"
    self.view.addSubview(self.label!)
    let horConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label!, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal,
                                           toItem: topLayoutGuide, attribute: .bottom,
                                           multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    let widthConstr = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label!, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)

    let heightConstr = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label!, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
    view.addConstraints([horConstraint, widthConstr, heightConstr])
}
```

With this being the result:

[image]

And I tried by setting the frame of my subview:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    self.label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: navigationBar.frame.height, width: 300, height: 100))
    self.label?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.label?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.label?.text = "label text"
    self.view.addSubview(self.label!)

}
```

And this came out:

[image]

In both cases my label covers part of the navigation bar. How to I fix this?

Comment: try give y position 64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Height of status bar is 20.You should consider status bar also while assigning `y` of your label. Your `viewDidAppear` should be

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    self.label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: navigationBar.frame.height+20, width: navigationBar.frame.width, height: 100))
    self.label?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.label?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.label?.text = "label text"
    self.view.addSubview(self.label!)
 }
```

Comment: better to set the label's y: navigationBar.frame.height + navigationBar.frame.y

Comment: Using constraints is so much better than making assumptions about the status bar height. Constraints also handle the nav bar changing height as well.

Answer (score 37):

### Swift

[image]

Try this code with `NSLayoutConstraint`.
newView will appear right under `NavigationBar`

```
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []//Optional our as per your view ladder

        let newView = UIView()
        newView.backgroundColor = .red
        self.view.addSubview(newView)
        newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            let guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
            newView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            newView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            newView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.topAnchor).isActive = true
            newView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        } else {
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView,
                               attribute: .top,
                               relatedBy: .equal,
                               toItem: view, attribute: .top,
                               multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView,
                               attribute: .leading,
                               relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view,
                               attribute: .leading,
                               multiplier: 1.0,
                               constant: 0).isActive = true
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: .trailing,
                               relatedBy: .equal,
                               toItem: view,
                               attribute: .trailing,
                               multiplier: 1.0,
                               constant: 0).isActive = true

                newView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        }
```

Comment: It works well but I noticed when you push to the next view controller there is a black background shown for a split second under the navigation control..can this be addressed?

Comment: i was looking this method since a day worked perfectly in swift 5

Comment: Confirmed working like a charm on iOS 13+ and Xcode 11.3.

Comment: This works with Objective-C and iOS 14 too, use `safeAreaLayoutGuide` could avoid those math stuff. At first I cannot determine where my UIView's top anchor should connect to.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calculating the height of the status bar with the navigation bar. In total they are 64, 44 nav bar and 20 for the status bar

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
self.label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: navigationBar.frame.height, width: 300, height: 100))
```

with

```
self.label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 64, width: 300, height: 100))
```

naviagtion bar & status bar together has a height of 64. Make it the y position

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: (navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)! + 20, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 40))
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
label.text = "Hello"
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
self.view.addSubview(label)

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having the same issue, or wants to have the same thing but with large title in the navigationBar you can add the code below to your subview constraints:

iOS 11.0 or above :

```
yourSubView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

iOS 11.0 or below :

```
yourSubView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score -1):

Frame of navigationBar is (0 20; 375 44), you can set label y position to 64.